# Combining two commands in a new command in Latex

Tags: macros, latex

I am trying to create a new command that will replace text with a blank line to write on. Essentially, the lovechild of, `\underline` and `\phantom` if it can be toggled on and off that would be even better but I seem to have a misunderstanding of how macros work in latex.

My crappy code is below

```
\newcommand{\rmv{}}{\Underline{\phantom{}}}
```

Comment: Maybe migrate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/? Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405762/defining-a-new-command-using-another-new-command.

Answer (score 2):

You're macro needs to know what text you want in the gap, so it needs an argument. The syntax to pass argument to the new macro is

```
\newcommand\macroname[number of arguments]{use the argument with #1 etc.}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifgaps
\gapstrue % comment/uncomment to toggle

\newcommand{\rmv}[1]{%
  \ifgaps%
    \underline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

test \rmv{test} test

\end{document}
```

(to automatically create two versions of your pdf with and without the gaps, you could use something similar to https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 )

Comment: is there a way of adding a minimum size for the line? I am new to programming in latex. (The line would need to be long enough for a student to write on not just the length of the typed word)

Comment: @ZacGotlib If you have a new question, please ask a new question